# ObservableCollection Sort extension method on key

Tags: c#, sorting, extension-methods, observablecollection

Hi I have an `ObservableCollection` in which where I add an item, I want to sort it.

I want to sort it on a key so for example:

```
collection.OrderByDescending(x => x.property)
```

I have created an extension method that will sort when the item is added too (`.Add`), however, the extension method needs to do something like the above code. Using the code from the extension method below, can someone help me?

```
public static void Sort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection) where T : IComparable
{
   List<T> sorted = collection.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
   for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
        collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sorted[i]), i);
}
```

Also does the generic really need to implement the `IComparable` interface? (I am very new to extension methods).

Comment: In the sort method, why are you sorting a list and then shuffling a second list to match the first ? Why not use the sorted list ?

Comment: I took this example from the web and wanted to understand it, I agree I dont need to do the loop, I thought I paste it to give a clearer understanding of what the sort can do. But you are right

Comment: This is probably one of the worst approaches to solve this problem; it has a complexity of `O(n²)`... and that's only after the sort itself

Comment: lol cheers for that, very helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346207/c-sharp-metro-windows-store-keeping-listview-sorted/25346385#25346385

Comment: I understand the sort algorithm but it doesn't sort it by descending on a property, it just inserts to the list where there isnt a duplicate. even though @ThomasLevesque could have said it better, he is right, this is overkill for what I need to do.

Comment: What kind of app is it? WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you use an `ObservableCollection<T>`, you don't sort it directly; instead, you apply a sort on the view of the collection ([ICollectionView interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx)). If you bind your UI directly to the `ObservableCollection<T>`, you can apply a sort like this:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MyProperty", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

You only need to do it once; if you add or remove items, the collection view will automatically re-sort itself. It also works if you change the value of `MyProperty`, provided that `T` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

See also: [How to: Get the Default View of a Data Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752284.aspx)

(I'm assuming that you're writing a WPF application; this approach won't work for Windows Phone or Windows Store apps)

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
ConceptItems = new ObservableCollection<DataConcept>(ConceptItems.OrderBy(i => i.DateColumn));
```

Comment: As an absolute professional, I up-voted the answer (Because it is a good answer) despite you being an Arsenal fan :)